# Pygame Top-Down Scrolling

Tags: python, pygame

For a project I want to do for my class' Pygame final, I want to make The Legend of Zelda: A Link To The Past. However right when I started I realized that the scrolling would be quite an issue.

How do you implement a scrolling technique that follows the player until the edge of a map or image but still allows the player to move closer to the edge?

A reference because I feel as if I am not correctly wording myself:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWyT9d8CiKY

My personal idea was to use a switch that switches the background image moving to Link's image moving.

Answer (score 2):

A major component of any branch of engineering is breaking down big problems into smaller ones. So let's break down your problem.

> How would you design a scrolling technique that follows the player
>   until the edge of a map or image but still allows the player to move
>   closer to the edge?

Okay, so there are three problems here. Moving the player sprite, moving the background sprite, and working out when to do each. Moving the player sprite is pretty straight forward - give it an (x,y) coordinate on the screen and move that according to the input controls (keyboard/mouse/etc).

Now let's consider the background sprite. For simplicity we'll assume that your whole background can be loaded as one big sprite. We want to render a portion of that background onto the screen - so we need to maintain the position of the background relative to the screen with it's own coordinates.

You can think about this two ways - either the screen stays stationary and the background moves behind it, or the background stays and the screen moves. Given that you'll eventually be tracking lots of other items (baddies, treasure, etc) and their position on the map, I would suggest thinking about everything moving relative to the background (even though this may seem less intuitive at first). Let's call this the world coordinate. To render things to the screen we'll need to work out their screen coordinate.

Okay, so we now have two coordinates - the positions of the screen and the player. For consistency, let's make the player position use world coordinates too.

So how do we render this to the screen? Start by listing out the rules:

1. the background should always fill the screen (i.e. don't scroll so far
   that you can see outside of the background sprite)
2. the player should be centred on screen, except when that would violate #1

So the position of the screen is dependent on the player, but with some limits depending on where it is on the map. Let's consider the `x` coordinate (note this is untested):

```
# start by centring the screen on the player
screen_x = player_x - screen_width/2
# limit the screen to within the bounds of the background
if screen_x < 0:
    screen_x = 0
if screen_x > (background_width - screen_width):
    screen_x = (background_width - screen_width)
```

You can now calculate the render position of the player (position on screen) by subtracting `screen_x` from `player_x`. The background render position is calculated the same way (but should result in a negative coordinate).

[image]

Comment: Holy cow, I did not expect this helpful of a reply. Thank you so much, I can tell how this would be way easier to implement than my own idea. Now for translating this idea to work with my code! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, good luck! The key is breaking it down into the simplest components. Think about what are the minimum variables that you could get away with and start there. When something seems hard, ask yourself "how can I break this down further", then repeat until it's an achievable task.

Comment: I am having trouble trying to implement moving the screen because we cant really move the screen without moving the background, correct? The screen is the actual pygame window.